# Access MQTT broker in Docker container

Tags: containers, ibm-cloud, mqtt, mosca

I hosting a Mosca MQTT broker in a node.js express app, and trying to run it in a container group in Bluemix. I'm having problems connecting to MQTT using port 1883 even though I've exposed port 1883 in my Dockerfile.

The MQTT broker is pretty simple:

```
var settings = {
  port: 1883,
};

var mqttserver = new mosca.Server(settings);

var httpServer = http.createServer(app);
mqttserver.attachHttpServer(httpServer);

var port = (process.env.VCAP_APP_PORT || 3000);

httpServer.listen(port, function(){
  console.log('Express server listening on port ' + port);
});
```

In my Dockerfile I expose port 80 and 1883

```
EXPOSE 1883
EXPOSE 80
```

When I create my container group in Bluemix I select port 1883. 
I can connect to the broker on port 80 but not on port 1883.

Any suggestions why not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[IBM Containers Scalable Group](https://new-console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/containers/container_group_ui.html) features **does not support non-HTTP traffic** for the exposed ports.

With this feature, an external URL is bound to the Go router serving the platform. HTTP requests made to port 80 on the external URL will be sent to the port you choose during configuration on the internal container hosts. You do not have direct access to the ports on the containers externally.

If you want to expose MQTT traffic, start the container as a single instance, rather than a group. You can choose to expose ports 1883 & 3000, allowing you to connect with HTTP requests and MQTT clients.

Comment: But IBM states that single instance containers are only for testing purposes, and I will loose the ability to scale in case of heavy traffic.

Comment: Singe instance containers are suitable for production purposes.
Does your service expect huge variations in traffic?

Comment: Yes it does. How do I best support this using a single instance container?